# Coloring N segments using M colors with dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

**Problem:** I have N contiguous segments numbered from 1 to N and M colors also numbered from 1 to M.
Now, there are two numbers U and V defined as:

- U = color(i) + color(j)
- V = color(j) + color(k)
- U, V are coprime.

where 1 <= i,j,k <= N and
j = i+1, k=j+1

Problem is to find the number of ways that all N segments can be colored such that the above property holds for all i,j,k.
Is there a dynamic programming solution to this problem? What is it?

Comment: Can you give us an example? It sounds like you want to figure out how to apply labels to cells in a 1xn grid, so that for every triple [a,b,c] (a+b) and (b+c) are coprime. For instance in [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3] -> 3 and 5 are coprime. [2,3,4] -> 5 and 7 are coprime.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes, this is exactly what I'm aiming for.

Comment: It's possible to determine recursively whether a given coloring has this coprimality property or not. if you have `[a,b,c ...]` you just check whether `(a+b)` is coprime with `(b+c)` and if it is, you check `[b, c]...`. If you have a recursive function, you can memoize it. If you have a way of traversing the memoization cache, then you have dynamic programming. That might help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes indeed. But you will need a sequence [a, b, c ....] to begin checking with. Are you suggesting I will need to recursively check all such possible colorings (m^n) for coprimality? Isn't there a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a recursive but non-[dynamic programming] implementation of this that should help get you pointed in the right direction. It's implemented in Common Lisp since there's no language specified.

The way to extend it to be a dynamic programming solution would be to add a cache.

`count-all-coprime-triple-colorings` constructs all the colorings in memory and then checks each of them for satisfying the coprime triple condition.

`count-all-coprime-triple-colorings-lazy` tries to aggressively prune the colorings we even consider by ruling out colorings with a prefix that doesn't satisfy the coprime condition.

This approach could be improved by noting that only the last two elements of the prefix are relevant, so you could use that to populate the cache.

```
(defun coprime-p (a b)
  "check whether a and b are coprime"
  (= (gcd a b) 1))

(defun coprime-triple-p (a b c)
  "check whether (a+b) and (b+c) are coprime"
  (coprime-p (+ a b) (+ b c)))

(defun coprime-triple-sequence-p (seq)
  "check whether seq is a sequence of corpime triples"
  (cond
    ;; if the length is less than 2 then
    ;; every triple is trivially coprime
    ((<= (length seq) 2) t)
    (t (let 
         ((a (nth 0 seq))
          (b (nth 1 seq))
          (c (nth 2 seq))
          (tail (cdr seq)))
         (if (coprime-triple-p a b c)
           (coprime-triple-sequence-p tail) 
          nil)))))

(defun curry-cons (x)
  "curried cons operator"
  (lambda (list) (cons x list)))

(defun all-colorings (sections colors)
  "generate all possible #colors-colorings of sections"
  (assert (>= sections 0))
  (assert (>= colors 1))
  (cond
    ;; if there are no sections
    ;; then there are no colorings
    ((= sections 0) ())
    ;; when we have one section there is one coloring
    ;; for each color
    ((= sections 1) (loop for i from 1 upto colors collecting (list i)))
    (t
      ;; wildly inefficient
      (loop for i from 1 upto colors appending
            (mapcar (curry-cons i) (all-colorings (1- sections) colors))))))

(defun count-all-coprime-triple-colorings (sections colors)
  "count all the colorings that have coprime triples"
  (loop for i in (all-colorings sections colors) counting (coprime-triple-sequence-p i)))

(defun coprime-triple-check-boundary (reversed-prefix suffix)
  "prefix = [...a, b] ; suffix = [c,...] ; check
  gcd(a+b, b+c) != 1"
  ;; if there aren't enough elements in reversed-prefix and suffix
  ;; then we admit the list
  (if (and (nth 1 reversed-prefix) (nth 0 suffix))
    (let 
      ((b (nth 0 reversed-prefix)) (a (nth 1 reversed-prefix)) (c (nth 0 suffix)))
      (coprime-triple-p a b c))
    t))

(defun count-all-coprime-triple-colorings-lazy (sections colors reversed-prefix)
  "count the number of sequences with coprime triples with a particular number
  of sections and colors with a particular reversed-prefix."
  (let
    ((sections-- (1- sections)))
    (cond
      ((= sections 0) 1) 
      (t (loop for i from 1 upto colors summing
            (if (coprime-triple-check-boundary reversed-prefix (list i))
              (count-all-coprime-triple-colorings-lazy sections-- colors (cons i reversed-prefix))
              0))))))

(defun summarize-coloring (i j)
  "summarize the given coloring number"
  (print (list "triples" i "colors" j 
               (count-all-coprime-triple-colorings-lazy i j nil))))

(loop for i from 1 upto 9 doing
      (loop for j from 1 upto 9 doing (summarize-coloring i j)))
```